# Select from two rows in the same table with SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

```
| postid | ref_postid | title   |
| 1      | 0          | Title 1 | 
| 2      | 1          |         | 
| 3      | 1          |         | 
| 4      | 0          | Title 2 | 
| 5      | 4          |         |
```

It´s a table for a discussion forum. When ref_postid = 0, that means it is a main post. When ref_postid is not 0 it is a answer and references to a postid, see table example above. (Only main posts has a title.)

I want to select all rows in the table, but the problem is that I want to display the title for the discussion an answer refers to.

Example: Let´s say I want the row where postid = 2, I also want to get "Title 1" which is the name of the discussion.

I tried doing it with CASE but I just got errors. I´m not very good at this. Is it doable with one query? Or  will I have to use two queries?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: This problem is best solved by redesigning your database tables, then the query won't arise. If that's not possible, look at joining the table to itself as a starting point.

Comment: How should I design the tables? I believe it´s a good idea to keep answers and questions in the same table since both have the same properties.

Comment: Personally, I'd see the relationship as a Parent-Child 1-many between questions and answers. I'd have a table for `Questions` with the `title` field and another for `Answers` with a FK on `postid` and no `title` field.

Comment: @Widor I had two different tables before, but it caused other problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select ifnull(q.title, a.title) title, ... (other columns)
from posts a
left join posts q on a.ref_postid <> 0 and a.ref_postid = q.postid
```